# Sql query where condition based on fetched column value

Tags: sql

I am making attendance system. I choose IN time for user for particular date using minimum time for the date and time greater than 4.00 AM. Now I want to find OUT time of user based on condition. Now OUT time can span across days. (because people work in night shift.). So condition for OUT time is maximum time of selected IN time plus 16 hours.

How can i write sql query for this?

My Database looks like this..

```
Name  Time                           In-0/Out-1
Ajay  1.00 AM 4/12/2012                 0
Ajay  6.00 AM 4/12/2012                 1
Ajay  9.00 PM 4/12/2012                 0  in time
Ajay  2.00 AM 5/12/2012                 1
Ajay  2.15 AM 5/12/2012                 0
Ajay  6.10 AM 5/12/2012                 1  out time
```

I am fetching IN and OUT time for user. Some people work in night shift. So **IN time** is fetched as min of today's IN time which is greater than 4 AM. And OUT time needs to be fetched as Max time of today's out time which is less than of 16 hour added to **today's IN time**.

Comment: Provide some smaple data and the result which is required

Comment: https://docs.google.com/open?id=0B6RTJEcZ5Bm4Sm5TYkVuMHVwZjg

Comment: I have added link to sample database.

Comment: I can not access yout provided link.